# Set up DRBD to replicate root LVM volume

Tags: debian, lvm, drbd

I have a server using /dev/vg1/root as its / mount. I am trying to set up DRBD so that ServerA's vg1-root is mirrored to another LVM volume on ServerB, vg1-ServerA-root.

I am able to create the metadata on ServerA's vg1-root, but I cannot attach the resource.

```
ian@ServerA:/etc/drbd.d$ sudo drbdadm attach all
open(/dev/vg1/root) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/vg1/root internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a blogpost[1] that comes with a tech guide explaining how put DRBD under the root FS. In your case it seems that / is currently in use which prevents DRBD from promoting the device.

[1] https://blogs.linbit.com/p/814/root-on-drbd-staging-server/